# Secondary Menu and Logged In Users

Tags: functions, menus, users, login, navigation

I'm using the below code to display two different menus in my storefront based child theme based on a users logged in status. But When I have a secondary menu (links by the search bar) it is replaced with the primary menu. Is there a way to differentiate between the two when checking for logged in users?

The below code is in my functions.php file.

```
//Custom Nav Menu
function custom_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
    }else { 
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
    } 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'custom_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

[image]
The theme is the default storefront theme, which should displays the secondary menu to the left of the search box. As you can see here its displaying (either) the logged-in or logged-out menu.

Please see Selected answer for more information.
My Working Code...

```
//Custom Nav Menu
function custom_wp_nav_menu_args($args) {
    if ( isset($args['theme_location']) && 'primary' === $args['theme_location'] ) {
            // do something
        if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
        }else { 
            $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
        }
    } 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'custom_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Comment: Could you add pictures to better understand your issue?

Comment: @himad I went ahead and added a screenshot. Please see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wp_nav_menu_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_args/) is a filter inside [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/), which is used to display navigation menus on your site. The `$args` parameter passed to the filter is an array containing the `wp_nav_menu` arguments. By default they are the following,

```
$defaults = array(
  'menu'            => '',
  'container'       => 'div',
  'container_class' => '',
  'container_id'    => '',
  'menu_class'      => 'menu',
  'menu_id'         => '',
  'echo'            => true,
  'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
  'before'          => '',
  'after'           => '',
  'link_before'     => '',
  'link_after'      => '',
  'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  'item_spacing'    => 'preserve',
  'depth'           => 0,
  'walker'          => '',
  'theme_location'  => '',
);
```

You can find these also in the `wp_nav_menu` code reference and in its source code. (These are merged with the theme supplied arguments by [wp_parse_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_args/) before being passed to the `wp_nav_menu_args` filter.)

This means you can use the parameter to check for example which location the filter is currently handling.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args_filter');
function my_wp_nav_menu_args_filter($args) {
  if ( isset($args['theme_location']) && 'my-theme-location' === $args['theme_location'] ) {
    // do something
  }
  return $args;
}
```

*(For Storefront the location slug is `secondary`, which you can find in the [source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/storefront/blob/169d3f5fd2f39fe52d19455ac9bafb761ae2f076/inc/storefront-template-functions.php#L276).)*

Comment: @t-thomas -- The answer by @antti-koskinen is great, but it is implying your answer:  you should be using the hook to check for the exact spot in which you desire to change the output (in this case, to the left of the search bar) **in addition to** performing your own `is_user_logged_in()` check.  Otherwise, you'll be modifying *every* spot where a menu appears on your site.  (The "do something" in @antti-koskinen 's code is where you would change the menu being displayed.)

Comment: Thank you @mort1305 for the clarification. Now as I read my answer again I realize it rather poorly worded and only implying the solution as you note.

Comment: It's an awesome answer, $antti-koskinen !